# JXBrowser, intercepting loading of a script, and change it's contents.

Tags: jxbrowser

I know you can add a LoadAdapter, and implement **onStartLoadingFrame**

but is it possible to modify the response? IE the content sent to the client. I cant seem to see the responseText anywhere yet to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CustomProtocolHandler to response with custom data.
Please take a loot at the [article](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000107014-custom-protocol-handler) for details.